# List of Whitehead-like Problems

Tags: soft-question, big-list, open-problems

Whitehead problem is a rather well known problem:

> Suppose that $G$ is an abelian group and $\mathrm{Ext}^1(G,\Bbb Z)=0$, is $G$ free?

It wasn't long before it was proved that if $G$ is countable (and thus countably-generated) then the answer is positive. However the question was open for uncountable groups, and it took more than a decade until Shelah came up with the interesting answer: *In ZFC the problem is undecidable*.

---

I was wondering what other open problems have somewhat of a Whitehead-like nature, namely they were proved for objects with a countable nature (e.g. separable topological spaces, countably generated), but the question remains open for the general case.

One example which comes to mind is [Naimark's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naimark%27s_problem) which was solved for separable $C^\ast$-algebras, and was partially solved in the general case in the sense that it is consistent to have a negative answer.

(As with CW big-lists, please post one problem per answer.)

Comment: What happens if you assume that the cardinality of $G$ is bounded? For example, suppose the cardinality of $G$ is at most that of $\mathbb R$, and the conditions hold - is $G$ free? (I don't know any logic or set theory, so this could be a naive question.)

Comment: @Peter: Shelah's independence result applies even in cardinality $\aleph_1$.

Answer (score 2):

One that - to the best of my knowledge - is still a huge open problem is about non-standard models of $PA$ and *Scott systems*. A Scott system $S$ is a set of reals such that $(\omega, S)\models WKL_0$; that is, $S$ is closed under Turing reducibility and has paths through all of its trees. Now, given a non-standard model of arithmetic $M\models PA$, we say a real $X$ is *coded in $M$* if $$ \exists a\in M\forall b\in M\cap\omega(M\models b\vert a\iff b\in X). $$ (It's a slight abuse of notation to write "$M\cap \omega$" for the standard part of $M$, but this is common.) The set of reals coded in $M$ is called the *standard system* of $M$ and is denoted by "$SSy(M)$."

A beautiful short argument shows that $SSy(M)$ is always a Scott set: infinite binary trees in $SSy(M)$ come from binary trees of nonstandard height in $M$, by an overspill argument, which must have paths of internally-finite but externally-infinite length; and these long paths corresond to infinite paths in $SSy(M)$. Conversely, it is easy to prove that every *countable* Scott set is the standard system of some model of $PA$.

The major open question is whether the stronger statement, "Every Scott set is the standard system of a model of $PA$," is true.

(Actually, we can do a bit better than "countable": by a union of chains argument, every Scott set of size $\le\aleph_1$ is a standard system, so in the presence of $CH$ the problem is solved. However, I still think this fits the question, because what's really going on is that countable=easy and $\aleph_1$ is "close enough" to countable to still be tractable.)